# How to Extends Mage_Core_Model_App class in Magento

Tags: magento, model, extends

Does anyone know how to extend `Mage_Core_Model_App` class in Magento?

I have set up my config.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
  <global>
    <models>
        <core>
           <rewrite>
                <app>My_Module_Model_App</app>
            </rewrite>
        </core>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

But Magento seems doesn't load it.

Is it good if I copy the `App.php` file to `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App` directory?

I'm not sure this way is good because if I right, I have to copy the whole code into it whereas I just have small modification.

Does anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your xml code to overwrite the core model looks good and would usually work. The problem with the class Mage_Core_Model_App is that it is instantiated directly using `new Mage_Core_Model_App()` in the method `public static function app()` in the file `app/Mage.php`

Rewriting core models in the xml way only affects classes loaded using Mage::getModel('core/app') and the like.

Therefore, unfortunately, your only option in this case is in fact to copy the file over to your app/code/local file structure and copy and paste the whole code, then edit it.

Usually, though, your xml rewrite structure would work perfectly and would be preferable to copying a whole class over. This particular core model is somewhat special.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search came up with http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api. I tried this on my local XAMPP installation. Just copy the file you want to edit into your app/code/local folder and keep the same directory structure. I edited /app/code/local/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php by copying the file from /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php and it worked as I expected. Hope this helps!